# DirectorySearcher issue (either sizelimit return objects or null values on objects?)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, active-directory

I've been grinding on this for quite a bit and keep hitting my head against the wall. I've read through tons of posts trying to figure it out but I'm obviously doing something wrong. When I use DirectorySearcher with Sizelimit under 1000, it works fine... (well, the *code* works fine, only returning the first 1000 presents a lot of issues :P) I'm trying to retrieve 4012 groups. So, I read that I need to use PageSize=1000 instead, which will return all objects on multiple pages. Great, that's what I needed.

My problem is, when I attempt to do that I get null values when trying to look at properties of each returned object. I'm not understanding why nor have I found other posts with the same issue... I imagine I'm doing something dumb as I'm new to C#, so I'm asking for someone to point it out to me :D

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm trying to get all distribution groups the currently logged in user either is the manager of or the co-manager of (in Exchange as an Owner, AD Value is "msExchCoManagedByLink") and display those groups in a ListBox.

**Function I'm trying to use to do this:**

```
    private void FillGroups()
        {
            DL_listBox.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<mydomain>");
            string DN = GetDistinguishedName();

            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=-2147483648)))");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("managedby");
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msExchCoManagedByLink");

                SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();
                foreach (SearchResult grp in result)
                {
                    List<string> DNs = new List<string>();
                    string mgr = grp.Properties["managedby"][0].ToString();
                    string g = grp.Properties["displayname"][0].ToString();
                    foreach (string t in grp.Properties["msExchCoManagedByLink"])
                    {
                        DNs.Add(t);
                    }
                    if (mgr == DN)
                    {
                        DL_listBox.Items.Add(g);
                    }
                    foreach (mgrc in DNs)
                    {
                        if (mgrc == DN)
                        {
                            DL_listBox.Items.Add(g);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error I get when I run this:**

On either of the lines using `grp.Properties[" "][0]`:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'

Looking through the information in the error, the properties value being returned is null. I don't understand why that is if it works when it's limited to 1000.

I read up on PrincipalSearcher a bit, but was unable to validate I could poll the co-manager value using it. I'm also not sure I wouldn't hit the same issue. Any advice would be appreciated, I'm gonna keep trying other things but felt I'm at a point to ask someone more experienced to avoid wasting more days on it :)

Thank you for reading, this is my first post :D

**Update:**

I was able to bypass this issue after a few hours of playing with it by doing the below:

```
  private void FillGroups()
        {
            DL_listBox.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<mydomain>");
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                //searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                searcher.SizeLimit = 200;
                searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=-2147483648))(managedby={0}))", GetDistinguishedName());
                searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");

                SearchResultCollection result = searcher.FindAll();
                foreach (SearchResult grp in result)
                {
                    string g = grp.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString();
                    DL_listBox.Items.Add(g);
                }

            }

            using (DirectorySearcher dsearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
            {
                //searcher.PageSize = 1000;
                dsearcher.SizeLimit = 200;
                dsearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=group)(!(groupType:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=-2147483648))(msExchCoManagedByLink:={0}))", GetDistinguishedName());
                dsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
                dsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("managedby");
                dsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msExchCoManagedByLink");

                SearchResultCollection result = dsearcher.FindAll();
                foreach (SearchResult grp in result)
                {
                    string g = grp.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString();
                    DL_listBox.Items.Add(g);
                }

            }
        }
```

I'd still like to understand why the initial code doesn't work though, if anyone could help me understand that I would be grateful! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer somewhere else, but figured I'd post it here in case anyone else ran into this oddity ;) When I looked at the debugger of what was being returned in user.Properties when the exception hit, I saw it was pulling a contact object that had "\" in the displayname. Adding (objectClass=user) to the LDAP query removed these and everything started working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding contact objects is probably a good thing to do anyway, but you still could run into this issue or a similar one. The issue is that those attributes are optional - they don't *have* to be populated with anything.

The exception you saw ("Index was out of range") I would only expect to see for a multi-value attribute, which both `displayName` and `managedBy` are not. Maybe you were using `grp.Properties["msExchCoManagedByLink"][0]` at some point?

In the case of a multi-value attribute, you will see an empty collection when it is not set. So when you try to access the value at index `0`, it throws that exception. You can avoid that by checking `grp.Properties["msExchCoManagedByLink"].Count` before trying to access the value.

However, even in your updated code, you could run into a null reference exception. The `displayName` attribute is not a required attribute either. When it is not set, the attribute will not exist in the `Properties` collection at all. (i.e. `grp.Properties["displayName"]` will be `null`) That means that `grp.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString();` will throw a null reference exception if `displayName` is not set. You can avoid this by either checking `grp.Properties.Contains("displayName")` before setting it:

```
string g = grp.Properties.Contains("displayName") ? grp.Properties["DisplayName"][0].ToString() : null;
```

Or use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-):

```
string g = grp.Properties["DisplayName"]?[0].ToString();
```

Comment: Hi Gabriel,

Thank you for reading through and answering ;) Yeah, I started to realize I needed to check for things before calling them when I tested in other environments ;) One thing I haven't figured out yet, when a displayName has a "/" or "&" I get the same indexing error. I'm not too sure how to exclude those :) 

Also, thank you for your examples.. I was doing similar but the above examples are much more elegant :) I was not aware you could use a null conditional operator in the array index like that.. very cool :)

Comment: That doesn't make sense that you'd get the same error when the `displayName` has a specific character. Can you show me the exact line that throws the exception and the exception message?